# how to display hours and minutes in allDay-slot in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to create a view in fullcalendar to show when some people are off duty.

People might be off the from eg. 10:00AM to 09:00AM the next day and I would like to show the event in the allDay-slot in fullcalendar and also show the start and end of the event as part of the title.

If I set the allDay-property on the event, it will display the event in the allDay-slot but it displays the start and end as '00:00' instead of '10:00' and '09:00'.

The other option I have tried is setting a custom property on the event-object called isDayOff, and then in the eventRender-callback set the standard allDay-property on the rendered event. This seems to work, but the event is not rendered in the allDay-slot on load, but only rendered in the allDay-slot when clicking back or forth to the prev/next day and then back.

How do I create this view?

I have created a fiddle to exemplify: http://jsfiddle.net/2ptqe5na/31

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title'
            },
            defaultDate: '2018-07-23',
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'A',
                    start: '2018-07-23T10:00:00',
                    end: '2018-07-24T09:00:00',
                    allDay: true //standard property
                },
                {
                    title: 'B',
                    start: '2018-07-23T08:00:00',
                    end: '2018-07-23T08:30:00',
                    isDayOff: true //custom property
                }
            ],
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
               alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element, view)
            {
              if(event.isDayOff==true)
              {
                event.allDay = event.isDayOff;
              }

              event.title = event.title+"\n "+event.start.format('MMM DD HH:mm')+" - "+event.end.format('MMM DD HH:mm');
          }
        });
});
```

Comment: "how to display hours and minutes in allDay-slot"...this is an oxymoron. All-day events don't have specified hours and minutes. They are always exactly 24 hours and always from the start of the day to the end of it. If it's "allDay" then you know it always starts and ends at midnight. That's the whole point of allDay events. If your events have different start and end times then, by definition, they are not classed as "allDay" (at least in the sense that fullCalendar uses that term)

Comment: e.g. your example "People might be off the from eg. 10:00AM to 09:00AM"...well in that case they're not off "all day"...on the first day they don't start being off until 10am. So from midnight and until 10am they are not "off", therefore it's not all-day. Likewise on the second day they're only "off" from midnight to 9am...after 9am that day they're on again according to your data. Again it's not "all-day".

Comment: So you either record these specific times and let the calendar display them at these times, or you decide that saying that the person is off "all-day" allows sufficient detail for your purpose and you accept that the exact times are lost and not displayed. It depends on what information you need to convey

Comment: P.S. if you want your eventRender hack to work properly, move all that code to to the "eventDataTransform" callback, then it will be executed _before_ the event has already been turned into a HTML element for displaying. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform .eventRender runs after the HTML element has already been created - updating the event properties at that moment is too late - hence why the change is only displayed next time the calendar is re-drawn. In eventRender you have access to the event properties so you can use them to update the `element` HTML, not to modify them

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your comments. I understand that "all day" is 24-hours but in this case the "allDaySlot" in Fullcalendar serves as the best way of displaying when people are off duty. I will look into eventDataTransform. Thanks again

Comment: Ok well then if that's the best way to display it, then you have to accept the trade-off that the information is a bit less accurate (i.e. doesn't convey the exact times involved). Like I said, it depends on your requirements as to what level of detail the person viewing the calendar needs to have.

Comment: I don't know if this would be helpful for your use case, but I found the 'businessHours' property to be helpful for showing when people are available. Probably not helpful if you aren't using 'resources'. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours